# Running and downloading Apache Spark without Scala Compilers

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying out spark for the first time, to sort of figure out how it works and present it. I am sure there is a duplicate, but I have not found it, in regards to how  to run Apache Spark. Do i absolutely require Scala to run it on my machine? I have the latest Java, so that is covered.

Comment: maybe you should try reading the documentation before asking questions on SO.

Comment: you should definitely read the documentation about that

Comment: Actually doing that right now haha

Answer (score 2):

Spark has Java, Scala, R and Python API. You can use any of this API and you need only Java to compile.

Answer (score 2):

Scala is not mandatory. There are 4 languages (Scala, Java, Python, R) available for Spark. You can use anyone of that.

Answer (score 2):

Basically Spark program can be written in four language

- Scala
- Java
- Python
- R
  To run the Scala Program you need a scala compiler and JDK
  For Java It needs JDK and Similar for python and R

Hope this helps!